# the table border-bottom disappear?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I try to implement a table with large size of data. then due to the performance issue, I just want to render the data in the body window.

But the new render element border disappear.

HTML:

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@2.5.15/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-template" id="list-template">
  <div class='table-body' ref="body" @scroll="handleScroll">
    <div class="list-view">
      <div     
        class="list-view-phantom"       
        :style="{
           height: contentHeight
        }">
      </div>
      <div class="list-view-colgroup">
         <div class="list-view-item-col-g" v-for='count in 5'>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div
        ref="content"
        class="list-view-content">
        <ul
          class="list-view-item"
          :style="{
            height: itemHeight + 'px'
          }"
          v-for="item in visibleData" :key='item.value'>
         <li class="list-view-item-col" v-for='count in 5'>
          {{item.value+count}}
         </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</script>
<div id="app">
  <template>
    <list-view :data="data"></list-view>
  </template>
</div>
```

JS:

```
const ListView = {
    name: 'ListView',

  template: '#list-template',

    props: {
    data: {
        type: Array,
      required: true
    },

    itemHeight: {
      type: Number,
      default: 30
    }
  },

  computed: {
    contentHeight() {
        return this.data.length * this.itemHeight + 'px';
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.updateVisibleData();
  },

  data() {
    return {
      visibleData: []
    };
  },

  methods: {
    updateVisibleData(scrollTop) {
        scrollTop = scrollTop || 0;
        const visibleCount = Math.ceil(this.$el.clientHeight / this.itemHeight);
      const start = Math.floor(scrollTop / this.itemHeight);
      const end = start + visibleCount;
      this.visibleData = this.data.slice(start, end);
      this.$refs.content.style.transform = `translate3d(0, ${ start * this.itemHeight }px, 0)`;
    },

    handleScroll() {
      const scrollTop = this.$refs.body.scrollTop;
      this.updateVisibleData(scrollTop);
    }
  }
};

new Vue({
  components: {
    ListView
  },

  data() {
    const data = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      data.push({ value: i });
    }

    return {
      data
    };
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

code example:

https://jsfiddle.net/441701328/hq1ej6bx/6/

you can see only the data render in the first time can have border.

could anyone help?

thanks all!!!

Answer (score 1):

table-row-group does not work with divs you can change the whole layout and use tables or instead you can do it like this.

```
.list-view-item {
        padding: 5px;
        color: #666;
        display: table;
        line-height: 30px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border-bottom: 1px solid red;
        min-width: 100vw;
    }

.list-view-item-col {
    display: table-cell;
    min-width: 50px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2eN3U/1/) for table-row-group

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display :flex` for `list-view-item` class, Try with following code.Hope it will work fine for you.

```
.list-view-item {
  padding: 5px;
  color: #666;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  line-height: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: this one could solve the border problem. but will make the table-column-group adjust the width not effective. I want to keep the table-column to adjust width.

Comment: Why should he do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this CSS. I hope it will works for you.

```
 .list-view-item {
    padding: 5px;
      color: #666;
      display:table;
      line-height: 30px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border-bottom: 1px solid green;
    }
```

Comment: Why should he try that?

Answer (score 0):

```
.list-view-item {
  padding: 5px;
  color: #666;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  line-height: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to change the js code :

```
this.$refs.content.style.transform = `translateY(0, ${ start * this.itemHeight }px, 0)`;
```

to :

```
this.$refs.content.style.transform = `translateY(${ start * this.itemHeight }px)`;
```

and add a css to  div class is list-view:

```
transform:translateY(0)px;
```

then the border showed.

don't understand why this action work!